# Postgres: two foreign keys to same primary key field

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys

```
create table date_dimension (
id serial primary key,
date_id date,
..... others
);

create table temp (
id serial primary key,
from_date integer,
to_date integer,
value integer,
foreign key (from_date, to_date) references date_dimension(id, id)
);
```

How can I refer both `from_date` and `to_date` to `id` field in `date_dimension`?
The current code fails to do that saying

```
ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "date_dimension"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

each `FOREIGN KEY` constraint added to a table will always relate *one* row in the referencing table to *one* row* in the referant.  If you want to have each row in the referencing to refer to two distinct rows in the referant, you need two, separate foreign key constraints.

you want:

```
foreign key (from_date) references date_dimension(id)
foreign key (to_date) references date_dimension(id)
```

You almost always want to have exactly the rows in the foreign key to be the same as the primary key in the referant.

<sup>* Actually, there may be more than one row in the referant if the foreign key is smaller than a candidate key of the referant.  this is seldom useful, though, and almost certainly unrelated to the problem you're describing</sup>

Comment: I see this now - ERROR:  column "id" of relation "date_dimension" already exists

Comment: @daydreamer: That sounds like a new problem, Please ask a new question with all of the code you have so far.

Comment: Hi @TokenMacGuy , this was due my my stupidity, your solution rocks! Thanks for that :)

Comment: And do you need to add indices here?